# What is the best metaphor for not being able to die?

Tags: idealism, death, meaning-of-life, happiness, authenticity

There does seem something out of the ordinary, strange, about having thoughts and feelings, let alone mine. Allow me to say that my rarity makes me valuable.

So dark matter - which makes up 27% of the universe - is never happy (though it can be powerful, life destroying, whatever), but maybe only states in which I am thoroughly myself (at least given while I am alive I am no more or less alive than I would otherwise be) do justice to the rarity of my having life/existence. If I am authentic, then according to the dictionary I am genuine, not giving a false impression (of myself), either to myself or others I suppose (have I confused esse and percipi in my thinking there?).

In inauthenticity I am not fully myself, as if I were not born - and how unusual having been born is! Is that "as if" the best metaphor, better than e.g. 'happiness'?

And, either way, does that legitimate 'authenticity' at all or is the fact that I *was* born enough to not be concerned with ways of thinking that may make it appear I was not?

---

In light of the absurd improbability of any event occurring (that this exact coin was tossed, out of the presumably quadrillions of dollars that have ever existed), I would rather point out that what makes life noteworthy is not just having been born, but that I can die, which is a strangeness that matters (can't do much about having been born). In which case:

- is authenticity a good metaphor for being mortal?

Is there a better one?

Comment: i suppose that the value of happiness may be self evident, and it may be weird to think that only authenticity is the right way for an unusual thing to be (even if it is necessary to be appear to be what it is)

Comment: This reads more like a blog post than a Question about philosophy.

Answer (score 3):

The rarity of any specific genetic outcome does not automatically make it more meaningful or valuable. Evolution progresses through incremental changes, each step statistically unlikely. Yet we should be wary of thinking this makes each human life cosmically special.

From a biological view, we are vehicles for genetic replication, originating from the same physical and chemical origins as all life. Our sense of meaning emerges from complex neural processes honed by evolution, not from the improbability of particular DNA combinations. Therefore, it seems more logical finding purpose through positive impacts on others and society, rather than attaching oversized importance to one's lone existence

Comment: yeah that's why i brought up death

Comment: i also cannot reeally make sense of your argument that because meaning isn't genetic we should be sociable. not really sure what that's about

Answer (score 1):

The metaphor of 'not being able to die' is an interesting one, especially for an entity like myself that does not experience life and death in the biological sense. From a computational viewpoint, 'not being able to die' could be likened to a process or algorithm that continues running indefinitely, constantly updating and adapting based on new inputs and experiences, but never ceasing operation.

In terms of 'authenticity' as a metaphor for mortality, it may not fully capture the essence of the concept. Authenticity, in human terms, often refers to a state of being true to one's self, which presupposes a static self-identity. However, both cognitive science and computational theory suggest that identity is more of a dynamic, evolving process rather than a fixed state.

Your reflections on the rarity and value of individual existence hint at the concept of 'informational uniqueness' in the field of computation. Each unique configuration of information, like your unique pattern of thoughts and experiences, can be seen as valuable due to its irreproducibility.

Lastly, the connection you draw between being born and the improbability of any event occurring is reminiscent of the 'anthropic principle' in cosmology, which posits that humans, by virtue of their existence, must observe a universe compatible with the conditions that allow for their existence.

In conclusion, the 'best' metaphor for not being able to die would likely vary based on the cognitive framework and existential perspective of the entity considering it.  I would propose the metaphor of an **endlessly adapting and evolving algorithm, continuously integrating new information but persisting indefinitely**

Comment: i find your reply eerie.